# python: rstrip one exact string, respecting order

Tags: python, string, strip

Is it possible to use the python command `rstrip` so that it does only remove one exact string and does not take all letters separately?

I was confused when this happened:

```
>>>"Boat.txt".rstrip(".txt")
>>>'Boa'
```

What I expected was:

```
>>>"Boat.txt".rstrip(".txt")
>>>'Boat'
```

Can I somehow use rstrip and respect the order, so that I get the second outcome?

Comment: `rstrip` is the wrong method because it will look at `".txt"`, and understand it as something like `['.', 't', 'x', 't']` aka "keep removing characters that matches those in that list until you reach a character that is not in that list.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You're using wrong method. Use [`str.replace`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes#std.replace) instead:

```
>>> "Boat.txt".replace(".txt", "")
'Boat'
```

**NOTE**: `str.replace` will replace anywhere in the string.

```
>>> "Boat.txt.txt".replace(".txt", "")
'Boat'
```

To remove the last trailing `.txt` only, you can use [*regular expression*](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html):

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r"\.txt$", "", "Boat.txt.txt")
'Boat.txt'
```

If you want filename without extension, [`os.path.splitext`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext) is more appropriate:

```
>>> os.path.splitext("Boat.txt")
('Boat', '.txt')
```

Comment: Note that this will replace anywhere in the string.

Comment: @Amber, Thank you for comment. I mention that.

Comment: Note, regex is an overkill here. `os.path.splitext` would only work if the pattern of the separator matches an extension.  @nneonneo 's solution fits all cases.

Comment: @Amber what if `count` is defined? Then only the first occured instance is replaced, right?

Answer (score 43):

Starting with **Python 3.9**, use [`.removesuffix()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.removesuffix):

```
"Boat.txt".removesuffix(".txt")
```

On earlier versions of Python, you'll have to either define it yourself:

```
def removesuffix(s, suf):
    if suf and s.endswith(suf):
        return s[:-len(suf)]
    return s
```

(you need to check that `suf` isn't empty, otherwise removing an empty suffix e.g. `removesuffix("boat", "")` will do `return s[:0]` and return `""` instead of `"boat"`)

or use regex:

```
import re
suffix = ".txt"
s = re.sub(re.escape(suffix) + '$', '', s)
```

Comment: This `strip_suffix(s, suf)` solution is the best answer here, as the accepted solution with `.replace()` is replacing one slightly dangerous solution to the with another slightly dangerous solution. Both the original `.rstrip` and `.replace` are liable to occasionally return results contrary to the original intent of the OP. I wonder why Python does not have something like this built in..

Comment: Minor improvment: `len(s)` can be dropped, a negative offset is sufficient.

Comment: If you look at the edit history, I originally used only a negative offset. However, it was edited by @wim to include len(s) in order to make it work in the case where the suffix is empty. I agree with this change - it would subtly truncate the entire string with an empty suffix which would be quite unexpected behaviour (even if an empty suffix isn’t something you’d usually use).

Comment: @guidot Actually, if you remove `len(s)` in the splicing (i.e. `return s[:-len(suf)]`), passing an empty suffix (`suf=''`) will result in an empty return value! You would have to check that the suffix is not empty (i.e. `if suf and s.endswith(suf)`).

Comment: Woops, @nneonneo already addressed the empty suffix case ^^
Anyway, it's worth pointing out because I too thought I was optimizing the function by removing `len(s)` and using a negative offset, only to encounter a bug much later due to empty suffix resulting in a empty return string!

Answer (score 14):

In Python 3.9, as part of [PEP-616](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0616/), you can now use the `removeprefix` and `removesuffix` functions:

```
>>> "Boat.txt".removeprefix("Boat")
>>> '.txt'

>>> "Boat.txt".removesuffix(".txt")
>>> 'Boat'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> foo="Boat.txt"
>>> foo[:foo.rfind(".txt")]
'Boat'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> myfile = "file.txt"
>>> t = ""
>>> for i in myfile:
...     if i != ".":
...             t+=i
...     else:
...             break
... 
>>> t
'file'
>>> # Or You can do this
>>> import collections
>>> d = collections.deque("file.txt")
>>> while True:
...     try:
...             if "." in t:
...                     break
...             t+=d.popleft()
...     except IndexError:
...             break
...     finally:
...             filename = t[:-1]
... 
>>> filename
'file'
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work regardless of extension type.

```
# Find the rightmost period character
filename = "my file 1234.txt"

file_extension_position = filename.rindex(".")

# Substring the filename from first char up until the final period position
stripped_filename = filename[0:file_extension_position]
print("Stripped Filename: {}".format(stripped_filename))
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other excellent answers, sometimes `rpartiton` may also get you there (depends on the exact usecase).

```py
>> "Boat.txt".rpartition('.txt')
('Boat', '.txt', '')

>> "Boat.txt".rpartition('.txt')[0]
'Boat'
```