# Python 2.7 Strict strip

Tags: python, string, strip

I have a string `string = 'some.value:so this-can be:any.thing, even some.value: too'`

I want to strip out the `'some.value:'` on the left side.

**My failed attempts:**

```
>>> string.lstrip('some.value:')
' this-can be:any.thing, even some.value: too'
>>> string.replace('some.value:','')
'so this-can be:any.thing, even  too'
>>> string.split(':')[1]
'so this-can be'
```

Expected output: `so this-can be:any.thing, even some.value: too`

I think the closest to my answer is using the `lstrip()`. How can I tell the `lstrip()` to strip exactly the whole phrase?

**[!] NOT** using any library is preferred!

**Note:** There is a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18723580/python-rstrip-one-exact-string-respecting-order) but the answer is not applicable to me.

Comment: You want to strip it out on the right or left side, output and question do not match

Comment: Oh sorry, my mistake. I messed up the side haha :D. Just edited the question. I want to strip the _left_ side.

Comment: @ProgrammerBeginner and does the target substring needs to be at the start or do you want to remove the first occurence wherever it is?

Comment: @OlivierMelançon, you guessed correctly that it has to be at the start. Thanks for the assistance. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We check if the string to strip is a the start, and cut the string if it is the case:

```
def strip_from_start(strip, string):
    if string.startswith(strip):
        string = string[len(strip):]
    return string

print(strip_from_start('value:', 'value: xxx value: zzz'))
# xxx value: zzz
```